# GRX FD-RX400 - full outer model?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front, grx

I'm just mounting the GRX FD-RX400. In the manual it says "if using a full outer model, ensure..."

What does full outer model mean and should I do that? :)

[image: A page from the Shimano GRX FD-RX400 mounting book]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a variant of this FD that is intended for frames with no housing stop at all for the cable housing. It features a housing stop that's integral to the derailleur itself. That's what they're talking about. They chose a confusing name for it because there are frames that have a housing stop near the FD/BB area that some would call a full or uninterrupted housing.

Comment: Thanks! My frame (Specialized AWOL Evo) has a cable stop that I have been using since it was new just under the bottom bracket so it sticks up behind the seat post. Should I use that one or the one built in to the derailleur?

Comment: @Ola If I were making that choice I would be looking at what option gives the smoother run for the cable and what option seems to leave the housing less vulnerable to water or dirt ingress. If I thought it made no difference either way, I would go for the frame stop on principle (lighter, less friction, but both only by whatever tiny marginal amount). It probably won't make much difference either way on your bike.